# Return updated value with PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

Is it possible to get the updated value on a row.
ex:
I get a table called 'invoice', in this table there is a field called 'balance'. I make an update on balance and I would like to get the new value of balance. 
Is it possible to return the new value of the affected field?

Comment: Upvoted because it is important for fluid interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can get only number of affected rows. If you want to have updated data you have to `SELECT` it.

BTW Database wouldn't know what to return - only updated fields? All rows? Whole resultset?

Comment: You could add a trigger for it though

Comment: Trigger for what? You need to explicitly tell database that you want data, it won't send anything by itself.

Comment: You can set a trigger to return a value after updating a column, init?

Comment: No, such trigger could change some data in other parts of the database, but still you'll need to fetch them in another query.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible but what you can do instead is return the number of affected row and if it is equal to 1 then 
it is safe to assume the new value has been updated in your balance field no need to return it.

```
$stmt->execute(array($new_value));

if($stmt->rowCount()==1){
     echo 'new Balance is = $'.$new_value;
}else{
     echo 'no row affected, no new value';
}
```